# How can I define a static instance of an abstract class?

Tags: c#, .net, static, abstract-class

I'm working with an abstract class in C# being inherited by multiple classes. One of the things I've been needing in my code is a static property such as "Unset", which would be a static instance of the class with it's main properties defined to an unset value. A generic example is as follows:

```
public abstract class Person
{
        public string Name {get; set;}
        public string PhoneNumber {get; set;}
        public static readonly Person Unset = new Person() {
            Name = "Unset Name"
            PhoneNumber = "Unset Phone"
        }
}
```

However I can't construct the "Unset" property because Person is an abstract class. I don't want to define the property for every class that derives from "Person". Is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create an instance of an abstract class.

What you can do, however, is create a new child:

```
public class UnsetPerson : Person
{
    public UnsetPerson() : base()
    {
        this.Name = "Unset Name";
        this.PhoneNumber = "Unset Phone";
    }
}
```

And then set the `static` property on your base class:

```
public abstract class Person
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
     public static readonly Person Unset = new UnsetPerson();
}
```

Comment: It's also important to note that having public setters on a singleton instance is a Really Bad Idea™.

Comment: I'm not sure if this suffices my project needs but it's definitely the solution to the question I asked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/sf985hc5.aspx) shows that the `abstract` keyword indicates that the thing being modified has a missing or incomplete implementation. As a result, it cannot be directly created, and can only be used through inheritance.

Since you don't (currently) have any abstract members in your abstract class, you could instead go with a `virtual` class, which allows you to provide a default implementation that can be optionally overwritten.

```
public virtual class Person
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public static readonly Person Unset = new Person() {
        Name = "Unset Name",
        PhoneNumber = "Unset Phone"
    };
}
```

If you don't need/want to override any of the class members in an inheriting class, you don't need to make an abstract or virtual class. Any (non-`sealed`) class can be inherited.

Comment: It was an example--my actual class needs to be abstract. But thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your requirements. Do you want to make sure that a freshly created instance of a derived class has those "unset" values? That could be done with a constructor in the abstract class:

```
protected Person()
{
    Name = "Unset Name";
    PhoneNumber = "Unset Phone";
}
```

Yes, an abstract class can have a constructor, even though you cannot instantiate it directly. The constructor of a base class is called before the constructor of a derived class, so that you can overwrite those "unset" values in the constructor of a derived class whenever it has appropriate parameters.

Comment: No, I needed a value to be able to reference statically. I have a lot of methods that will be expecting instances of this class, and I am having to handle a lot of logic for undefined/null cases. 

I figured having a default or unset value to be able to work with was easier than handling all the null cases I had.